# Dynamically generate DatePicker controls on the basis of Database values

Tags: c#, loops, datepicker

I have multiple rows inside the database table

```
Id  QId     QName       QText   QType       Version
5   10025   DateFrom    From    DateRange   1
5   10026   DateTo      To      DateRange   1
```

I want to dynamically generate `DatePicker` controls on the basis of values from this database table. My question is to use `QName` and `QId` to differentiate between From (smaller id) and To (greater id) to generate the controls, and apply `CompareValidator` to to check the `Date Range Validation`. I loop through controls on the basis of Id.

Here is my code to generate controls.

```
case "DateRange":
   RadDatePicker rdpDateFrom = new RadDatePicker();
   rdpDateFrom.CssClass = "form-control form-control-item";
   rdpDateFrom.ID = "rdpDateFrom" + j.ToString() + "-" + counter;
   rdpDateFrom.AutoPostBack = false;
   rdpDateFrom.DatePopupButton.Visible = true;
   rdpDateFrom.ShowPopupOnFocus = true;
   rdpDateFrom.EnableScreenBoundaryDetection = true;
   rdpDateFrom.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;

   txtC1.Controls.Add(rdpDateFrom);

   RadDatePicker rdpDateTo = new RadDatePicker();
   rdpDateTo.CssClass = "form-control form-control-item";
   rdpDateTo.ID = "rdpDateTo" + j.ToString() + "-" + counter;
   rdpDateTo.AutoPostBack = false;
   rdpDateTo.DatePopupButton.Visible = true;
   rdpDateTo.ShowPopupOnFocus = true;
   rdpDateTo.EnableScreenBoundaryDetection = true;
   rdpDateTo.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;

   txtC1.Controls.Add(rdpDateTo);

   CompareValidator cvdpDate = new CompareValidator();
   cvdpDate.ID = "cvdpDate" + j.ToString() + "-" + counter;
   cvdpDate.ControlToCompare = "rdpDateFrom" + j.ToString() + "-" + counter;
   cvdpDate.ControlToValidate = "rdpDateTo" + j.ToString() + "-" + counter;
   cvdpDate.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.GreaterThanEqual;
   cvdpDate.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
   cvdpDate.ErrorMessage = "End date must be equal or greater than start date - please correct dates.";

   txtC1.Controls.Add(cvdpDate);
break;
```

Comment: what is the problem in above code?

Comment: I want to generate controls on the basis of QId, like Smaller QId for From and Larger QId for To.

Comment: Actually I want to differentiate between date pairs and singular date inputs. In the same db table I have singular dates also.

Comment: still im not getting you, can u please elaborate the issue with an update. The above db data contains 2rows, do you want to do some functions based on these two rows?  Or just add some more db data rows so that everyone can understand

Comment: Yea, I want to do some functions based on these 2 rows. I need to create controls on the basis of these 2 rows. I am getting these rows in the datatable and than have to generate controls on the basis of values, like I have QId 10025 so it should create 'From' DatePicker control and The next QId should create 'To' DatePricker control.